# losing null values filtering sql query results using where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a complex query which joins more than 7 tables.
After the joins, I would like to filter the result of my query .

Here is something that I observed.

When I do a where clause

```
where X.Name != 'xxx'
and  XY.Product != 1
```

I get the filtered results , but all the null values for the X.Name and XY.Product also disappear 
from my result. I would like to retain the null values.

I also tried :

```
and X.Name != 'xxx'
and  XY.Product != 1
```

I removed the where clause totally and put in an and , but I dont see the filtering at all by this approach.

Is there a way I can filter my results without losing the null values ??

Comment: Null has interesting equality properties.  Try switching too `AND NOT X.Name == 'xxx'`.

Comment: Have you verified that you have all the NULLs after your joins?  Common mistake is when doing multiple joins is to do `INNER JOIN` **after** `OUTER JOIN`. This *could* negate `OUTER JOIN` effect

Comment: Suspect you have outer joins.  Checking for = or != in the where kills the outer.  See solution from das.

Answer (score 10):

Try something like:

```
where (X.Name <> 'xxx' or X.Name is null)
  and (XY.Product <> 1 or XY.Product is null)
```

Since, by definition `NULL` is an unknown value (bit simplified but OK for this explanation), it will neither equal or not equal a given value - that's why the `IS NULL` is required here.

Answer (score 4):

This quote is taken from 70-461 training kit.

**"T-SQL—again, based on standard SQL—implements only one general purpose mark called NULL for any kind of missing value.  This leads to three-valued predicate logic."**

Therefore, here are the three logic conditions you can have.

1 - Value matches condition 
2 - Value does not match condition
3 - Value is missing.

Here is some sample code to play around with.

```
-- Create sample table
create table #products
( 
  my_id int identity (1, 1),
  my_name varchar(16)
);

-- Load with sample data
insert into #products (my_name) values
(NULL),
('iPad'),
('Windows Surface');

-- Show the data
select * from #products

-- Show just ipads
select * from #products where my_name = 'iPad'

-- Show just surfaces
select * from #products where my_name <> 'iPad'

-- Show ipads & unknowns
select * from #products where my_name = 'iPad' or my_name is null
```

Here is the output from the last three select statements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
where (X.Name != 'xxx' or X.name Is Null)
and  (XY.Product != 1 or XY.Product Is Null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X.NAME,XY.PRODUCT FROM

(SELECT ID,NAME FROM TABLE_X WHERE NAME!=1)X
OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ID,PRODUCT FROM TABLE_XY WHERE PRODUCT!=1)XY
ON X.ID=XY.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:
where isnull(X.Name,'') != 'xxx' and  isnull(XY.Product,0) != 1