# How to return NULL records on a query with a where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I have a view setup for novice end users.
To start, let's say there is a table like the following:

```
id  number
=========
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   NULL
5   12
```

If a user makes a query on the *view* such as, `select * from view1 where number <> 12`, the view is setup to return NULL values as -99 using `coalesce(number,-99)`:

```
Result of 'select * from view1 where number <> 12':
id  number
=========
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   -99
```

Is there anyway to have the view return NULL instead of -99 (or whatever value), without the end user having to include `... or where is null` in their query?

I understand NULLs and why it behaves like this, but for convenience I'd rather these end users not have to do this.

Comment: Here is a good read on why what you are asking can't be done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964473/losing-null-values-filtering-sql-query-results-using-where

Answer (score 0):

No.

The best you can do is fix the result so it decodes `-99` as `NULL`:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN number = -99 THEN NULL ELSE number END AS number
FROM view1
WHERE number != 12
```

which I believe defeats the purpose of not exposing `NULL` values to the end user, or approach the data by accounting `NULL` as a valid data, using `OR number IS NULL` in that matter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select * from view1 where number <> 12 or number is null
```

Comment: The question explicitly said "without the end user having to include ... or where is null in their query"